# upgrade to kendo framework and login function is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, kendo-ui

I am new here and I was wondering if anyone can help me.
I developed a website ( ASP.net , MVC , C#) and it was working fine, since 2 months ago I used the Kendo UI framework to improve some page design and grids , .. and since then I have a problem with login functionality. I can login fine but all the users who are using our company network have a problem with login ( they can log in but they are redirected to Unauthorised access page !) I have not done any changes in the login page at all. since I cannot find the reason for the problem I just ask the to try to login again or login / logout or empty the cache ...
Any one have  any idea that what might go wrong here?
thanks

sorry here is my code for login page

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4>Login
        </h4>
        <div>
            <div>
                @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(false);
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe) Remember me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="submit btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-lock"></i>Login</button>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div class="ribbon"></div>
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/search.png")" title="Detailed Search Facility" />
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/charts.png")" title="Exception Charts" />
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/mtbe.png")" title="Mean Time Between Exception Analysis" />
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/pm-compliance.png")" title="PM Compliance" />
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/cost-analysis.png")" title="Cost Benefit Analysis" />
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('#slider').nivoSlider();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller code:

```
    public class AccountController : Controller {

        private HashUtility hashUtility = new HashUtility();

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index() {
            var companyName = this.GetCurrentCompanyName();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(companyName)) {
                return RedirectToAction("SelectCompany");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }

        #region Select Company

        [HasPermission(Category.SELECT_COMPANY)]
        public ActionResult SelectCompany() {
            this.SetTitle("Select Company");

            var model = new List<CompanyModel>();

            using (var context = DbConnectionFactory.CreateDataContext()) {
                model = context.Companies                    
                    .OrderBy(c => c.Name)
                    .Select(c => new CompanyModel{                       
                        CompanyId = c.CompanyId,
                        Name = c.Name,
                        HasLogo = c.Logo!=null && c.Logo.Length > 0
                    })
                    .ToList();
            }

            return View(model);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Login

        public ActionResult Login() {
            this.SetTitle("Login");

            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) {
                this.SetTitle("Login");
                return View();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model) {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
                return View(model);
            }

            bool loginFailed = false;
            string companyName = null;


            using (var context = DbConnectionFactory.CreateDataContext()) {

                var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(a => (a.Username == model.Username || a.EmailAddress == model.Username));

                if (user == null) {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,
                        "An account does not exist with the user name provided.");
                    return View(model);
                }

                if (user.IsLocked) {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,
                        "This user account is disabled, please contact helpdesk for support.");
                    return View(model);
                }


                if (hashUtility.VerifyHashString(model.Password, user.Password, user.Salt)) {                    
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, model.RememberMe);                                                                       
                    companyName = user.Company!=null ? user.Company.Name : null;
                    //model.Accessed = DateTime.Now;
                    //user.Accessed = model.Accessed;



                } else {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,
                        "Incorrect username or password provided for this account, please verify and try again.");
                    loginFailed = true;
                }

            }

            if (loginFailed) {
                return View(model);
            } else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.ReturnUrl)) {
                return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
            } else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(companyName)) {
                return RedirectToAction("SelectCompany");
            } else {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { @company = companyName });                            
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Change Password

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult ChangePassword() {
            var model = new ChangePasswordModel();
            return View(model);
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordModel model) {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
                return View(model);
            }

            using (var context = this.CreateAuditContext()) {
                var user = this.GetCurrentUser(context);

                if (model.NewPassword != model.ConfirmNewPassword) {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("ConfirmNewPassword",
                        "New password and password confirmation do not match");
                    return View(model);
                }

                if (hashUtility.VerifyHashString(model.CurrentPassword, user.Password, user.Salt)) {

                    string passwordHash;
                    string salt;

                    hashUtility.GetHashAndSaltString(model.NewPassword, out passwordHash, out salt);

                    user.Password = passwordHash;
                    user.Salt = salt;

                    context.SubmitChanges();

                    this.SetMessage(Models.MessageType.Success,
                        "Password has been successfully changed for this account");
                } else {
                    this.SetMessage(Models.MessageType.Error,
                        "Incorrect password provided for this account, please verify and try again.");
                    return View(model);
                }

                context.CompleteTransaction();

            }

            return RedirectToAction("ChangePassword");
        }

        #endregion

        #region Unauthorised

        public ActionResult Unauthorised() {
            this.SetTitle("Unauthorised Access");
            return View();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Logout

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Logout() {            
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

unauthorized access view

```
<h2>
    Unauthorised Access</h2>
<p>
    This user account does not have the authorisation to access this area of the system.</p>
@if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) {
   @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }) 
}
```

Has permission attribute:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Attribute determining if a user has a particular permission 
    /// defined by its IPermissions profile
    /// </summary>
    public class HasPermissionAttribute : IsAuthorizedAttributeBase {

        private Category category;
        private AccessType? access;

        public HasPermissionAttribute(Category category) {
            this.category = category;
        }

        public HasPermissionAttribute(Category category, AccessType access) {
            this.category = category;
            this.access = access;
        }

        public override bool IsAuthorized(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
            if (httpContext == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
            }

            if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
                return false;
            }           

            using (var context = DbConnectionFactory.CreateDataContext()) {
                var userName = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
                var role = context.Users
                    .Where(u => u.Username == userName && !u.IsLocked)
                    .Select(u => u.Role).SingleOrDefault();

                if (role == null)
                    return false;

                IPermissions profile = UserRoleUtility.GetPermissionProfile(role);
                if (access.HasValue)
                    return profile.HasPermission(category, access.Value);
                else
                    return profile.HasPermission(category);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And how is anyone supposed to help without any code??

Comment: Sorry , here is the login View code

Comment: what type of authentication you are using forms,windows...anyother..???

Comment: it is a form <authentication>

Comment: I don't see any code for redirection to Unauthorised access nor filter. if you are determine user authorization using filter then post the code...

Comment: still do not see any redirection to Unautherized view in the filter it self....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about IsAuthorizedAttributeBase attibute. 
I am using AuthorizeAttribute and overriding HandleUnautherized method this in mvc 4.0 and it works like a charm.

**********************Fitlers*********************

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;


 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public sealed class FilterAuthAttribute:AuthorizeAttribute
    {
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // If the browser session has expired...
        if (ctx.Session["UserName"] == null)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                // For AJAX requests, we're overriding the returned JSON result with a simple string,
                // indicating to the calling JavaScript code that a redirect should be performed.
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult { Data = "_Logon_" };
            }
            else
            {
                // For round-trip posts, we're forcing a redirect to Home/TimeoutRedirect/, which
                // simply displays a temporary 5 second notification that they have timed out, and
                // will, in turn, redirect to the logon page.
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                    { "Controller", "Home" },
                    { "Action", "TimeoutRedirect" }
            });
            }
        }
        else if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Otherwise the reason we got here was because the user didn't have access rights to the
            // operation, and a 403 should be returned.
            //filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(403);
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                    { "Controller", "Home" },
                    { "Action", "Unauthorized" }

        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }   

 }
```

regards

## shaz

Comment: many thanks Shaz, but the website was working fine for the past 3 years and even now it is totally fine on my machine and many other users , just some random users have issues with login , and at the same time when I use their login details to login from my machine it is totally working , is it possible that browsers cause the problem? I mean is it anything in the Kendo UI which is not working with older version of IE fro example?

Comment: it got nothing to do with kendo UI mate... you did not handle uthorization and session very well you are only checking Request.IsAuthenticated... so what happens if the session time-out and  form auth time-out..thats why other user get authorize redirect

Comment: and you are only using 1 filter which is only checking Request.IsAuthenticated..bascilly you need 2 filters.. 1 for sesssion expiry and redirect to login and 2. to unautherized access and redriect to un-authorize access view ....

Comment: most developers got confused with form timeout and session time out and thinks its a same thing but infact its not have a read on it and here are 2 fitlers for checking session time out and unauthorized access http://markfreedman.com/index.php/2012/02/28/handling-session-and-authentication-timeouts-in-asp-net-mvc/